# Difference between inc si and si +1 in x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I have an array like this in x86[assembly]:

```
pos[si]
```

To run the array, is any difference between

```
inc si
pos[si]
```

and

```
pos[si+1]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one increments `SI` permanently while the other does it only for the current instruction. The former is slower because it requires two instructions.